# javascript applied border for group of absolute positioned images

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to apply a border to a div group of images (that need to be in absolute position mode, because the user select and move them around), and for some reason can't figure out why it doesn't work.  In my code, I move the images around inside the div container, and want the overall div container to show a proper border, based on the size of the things inside.  Here is some simplified code, perhaps only one small bug, I can't see it, to get it working.

Editing the code, after someone puts it into a snippet, is buggy for some reason.  Here's one code fix: fixBorder() to tryBorder()

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
.item {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}

.mouseover { border:1px dashed green; }

</style>
<script>
function id(name) { return document.getElementById(name); }
function tryBorder() {
    var w1 = id("part-1").style.width.replace("px", "");
    var h1 = id("part-1").style.height.replace("px", ""); 
  var l1 = id("part-1").style.left.replace("px", "");
  var t1 = id("part-1").style.top.replace("px", "");

    var w2 = id("part-2").style.width.replace("px", "");
  var h2 = id("part-2").style.height.replace("px", ""); 
  var l1 = id("part-2").style.left.replace("px", "");
  var t1 = id("part-2").style.top.replace("px", "");

  // "math" for the group size and position
  var wOverlay = l2 - w1;
  var hOverlay = t2 - h1;

  var wg = w1 + w2 - wOverlay;
  var hg = h1 + h2 - hOverlay;

  var lg = ( l1 < l2 ) ? l1 : l2;
  var tg = ( h1 < h2 ) ? h1 : h2;

  // ok, now how to I apply that math? is it easy? 
    id('group').onmouseover = function(event) {  
      alert("on mouseover");
    if (! event.shiftKey) elem.classList.add('mouseover'); 
    else elem.classList.remove('mouseover');
  }

  id('group').style.left = lg + "px";
  id('group').style.top = hg + "px";

  id('group').style.width =  width + "px";
  id('group').style.height = height + "px";
} 
</script>
</head>
<body onload="tryBorder();">
<div id="group" style="border:5px solid red">
  <img id="part-1" class="item" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/"> 
  <img id="part-2" class="item" src="https://dummyimage.com/300/09f.png/fff">  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. `SyntaxError: missing } after function body` 2. you probably want to assign `l2` and `t2`

Comment: thanks Chris, I added in my code. I can't figure out why the mouseover isn't working, do you see the bug there?

Comment: You are missing an opening bracket in your if statement, and also I don't see where you're calling the fixBorder function (that has the mouseover function inside it)?

Comment: i answer u , i hope to understood u correct , try code i upload it

Comment: No, you didn't get it.  The user will be able to pick up the images and move them around.  So, after they are done, I want to re-compute the overall div/group size, and apply the correctly sized border.

Comment: does anyone see, why the mouseover doesn't work, for some reason? Just to begin with ...

Answer (score 0):

if i understood u try this code

```js
function id(name) { return document.getElementById(name); }
function tryBorder() {
    var w1 = id("part-1").style.width.replace("px", "");
    var h1 = id("part-1").style.height.replace("px", ""); 
  var l1 = id("part-1").style.left.replace("px", "");
  var t1 = id("part-1").style.top.replace("px", "");

    var w2 = id("part-2").style.width.replace("px", "");
  var h2 = id("part-2").style.height.replace("px", ""); 
  var l1 = id("part-2").style.left.replace("px", "");
  var t1 = id("part-2").style.top.replace("px", "");

  // "math" for the group size and position
  var wOverlay = l2 - w1;
  var hOverlay = t2 - h1;

  var wg = w1 + w2 - wOverlay;
  var hg = h1 + h2 - hOverlay;

  var lg = ( l1 < l2 ) ? l1 : l2;
  var tg = ( h1 < h2 ) ? h1 : h2;

  // ok, now how to I apply that math? is it easy? 
    id('group').onmouseover = function(event) {  
      alert("on mouseover");
    if (! event.shiftKey) elem.classList.add('mouseover'); 
    else elem.classList.remove('mouseover');
  }

  id('group').style.left = lg + "px";
  id('group').style.top = hg + "px";

  id('group').style.width =  width + "px";
  id('group').style.height = height + "px";
}
```

```css
#group{
  border:5px solid red;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 600px;

}
.item1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 100%;

}
.item2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  max-width: 100%;

}

.mouseover { border:1px dashed green; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="group">
  <img id="part-1" class="item1" src="https://dummyimage.com/640x4:3/"> 
  <img id="part-2" class="item2" src="https://dummyimage.com/300/09f.png/fff">  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that doesn't work though.  It's too large, the border.  What's wrong?  And you cannot set the group height that way.  It must be computed, as the user will be moving the images around inside the group.